# Integral of derivative of Legendre polynomials

Tags: legendre-polynomials

Show that:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m'(x)dx=\frac{2l(l+1)}{2l+1}\delta_{lm}.$$

So here's what I have: 
$$[(1-x^2)P_n'(x)]'=-n(n+1)P_n(x)$$ (from the original DiffEq), and the orthogonality relation 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}P_m(x)P_n(x)dx=\frac{2}{2n+1}\delta_{mn}.$$ Now, integrating by parts gives:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m'(x)dx=\left.(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m(x)\right|_{-1}^{1}-\int_{-1}^{1}-l(l+1)P_l(x)P_m(x)dx$$

$$=\left.(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m(x)\right|_{-1}^{1}+\frac{2l(l+1)}{2l+1}\delta_{lm}.$$

I think this is the right way to go about this problem, but I don'tknow how to get rid of that $(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m(x)$ term. Thoughts?

Comment: Evaluate the quantity $(1-x^2)P_l^{'}(x)P_m(x)$ at the limits $1,-1$.

Comment: Well, apparently it's been too long since I've done a definite integration by parts... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, term $(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m(x)$ should be $(1-x^2)P_l'(x)P_m(x)|_{x=-1}^{x=1}$ which naturally gives $0$.

General formula:

$$\int_a^b uv' = [uv]|_a^b - \int_a^b vu'$$

Comment: Yes I'm not sure how that one got past me. Thanks.